# Required="true" not working with apex:inputsecret

Tags: visualforce

I am using `apex:inputsecret` with `required="true"`, but this is not working. When I check in Inspect element of Chrome, the required attribute is not shown. 
If I add `required="true"` from Inspect element then it works. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: This may be an issue where SF doesn't put in the required marker or enforce it. Have a look at [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9723/radio-button-required-true-not-displaying-an-error-message-when-no-selection) to see if it helps

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce does not add the `required` HTML attribute to your fields when setting `required="true"` on a component.

Setting the component's `required` attribute indicates that Salesforce should validate that the field is required on the server-side. This differs from the HTML version of the `required` attribute which does the validation on the client-side.

What you are seeing is the expected behaviour.

If you add an `apex:pageMessages` component to your page and try and call an `action` or anything that will submit your form then you should get an error message if your `apex:inputSecret` is blank.

Answer (score -3):

```
<input id="theSecretInput" type="password" name="theSecretInput" value="" required=true />
```

Try the required field as a boolean instead of a string. As suggested by the documentation here : 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputSecret.htm

Comment: `required="true"` is the correct format. Your code example will produce a "**Open quote is expected for attribute "required" associated with an element type "input"**" error without the quotes.

Comment: yes @BarCotter is right this not work